# Loading external dependences with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using some external libraries such a google maps in some of my views in my angular app.

As this is a relatively minor use case, I'd like to load google maps only when the views is called.
So far, I've tried loading the js directly in my views template:

```
<div class='myView'>
    <script type'text="" javascript="type'text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" class="ng-scope"></script>
</div>
```

I can see the javascript is requested an well received in the chrome dev tool Network tabs however it is not parsed as `window.google` remains undefined.

How can I compile it? Is there a better way to do it? Can it be done using the `resolve` function exposed by ui-router?

Many thanks